# Getting impact wrench into narrow space

Tags: wrench, driver

I am removing some sway bar links and need to remove a rusted nut from a narrow space.  There is not enough room for my impact wrench.

I know how to get a bolt off with a torch, cutter, splitter, etc. But, I'm wondering if there is some kind of tool that will extend the impact wrench force along a shaft which holds the socket?  (So I can slide that into the narrow space)

I'm not talking about a U-joint, there's no room for that.  I'm wondering if there is a tool/add-on for the impact wrench that keeps the original angle (or shifts is 180'), but 6 inches to the side.  No idea what it's called or what it looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An “extension wrench” or “offset extension wrench” could be the tool you are looking for. For example, a [1/2" Professional Tite-Reach Extension Wrench](https://tite-reach.com/products/1-2-professional-tite-reach-extension-wrench).

I am not affiliated with Tite-Reach. Their tool just seems to be one of the sturdier ones (“rated on an impact for up to 1,200ft/lbs and 225ft/lbs of direct torque”).

[image: Impact wrench with offset extension wrench]

Comment: Bingo!!  It even works 0' or 180'.  I knew such a thing must exist...I just could not find it without knowing the name of it.

Comment: Looks like it could be what you need for sure @TSG, my main thought with that is to make sure it's braced well when you use it!

Comment: You know ... I knew these existed ... no clue why I didn't remember ... deleted my answer with an upvote on yours. Well done.